# sympy hangs when trying to solve for simultaneous equations with cubics and trig

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve for this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370530/equation-of-a-cubic-bezier-curve/4370920#4370920

Here's the full code

```
from sympy import *

xa=symbols('xa')
xb=symbols('xb')
xc=symbols('xc')
xd=symbols('xd')
xe=symbols('xe')
xf=symbols('xf')
xg=symbols('xg')
xh=symbols('xh')
xi=symbols('xi')
xm=symbols('xm')
xn=symbols('xn')
ya=symbols('ya')
yb=symbols('yb')
yc=symbols('yc')
yd=symbols('yd')
ye=symbols('ye')
yf=symbols('yf')
yg=symbols('yg')
yh=symbols('yh')
yi=symbols('yi')
ym=symbols('ym')
yn=symbols('yn')

p=symbols('p')
q=symbols('q')

alpha,beta=symbols("alpha,beta")

pxe = xa+p*(xb-xa)
pxf = xb+p*(xc-xb)
pxg = xc+p*(xd-xc)
pxh = xe+p*(xf-xe)
pxh = pxh.subs(xe, pxe).subs(xf, pxf)
pxi = xf+p*(xg-xf)
pxi = pxi.subs(xf, pxf).subs(xg, pxg)
pxm = xh+p*(xi-xh)
pxm = pxm.subs(xh, pxh).subs(xi, pxi)
pxm = simplify(pxm)
pym = pxm.subs(xa, ya).subs(xb,yb).subs(xc,yc).subs(xd,yd)

ab = symbols("ab")
cd = symbols("cd")
lxb = xa + ab*sin(alpha)
lxc = xd + cd*sin(beta)
lyb = ya + ab*cos(alpha)
lyc = yd + cd*cos(beta)

pxm = pxm.subs(xb,lxb).subs(xc,lxc)
pym = pym.subs(yb,lyb).subs(yc,lyc)

eqxm = Eq(xm, pxm)
cdx = solve(eqxm, cd)[0]
eqym = Eq(ym,pym)
cdy = solve(eqym, cd)[0]
eqcd = Eq(cdx, cdy)
abp = solve(eqcd, ab)[0]
abq = abp.subs(p,q).subs(xm, xn).subs(ym,yn)
print(abp)
print(abq)
eqpq = Eq(abp, abq)
qv = solve(eqpq, q)
print(qv)
```

I get

```
abp = -(2*p**3*xa*cos(beta) - 2*p**3*xd*cos(beta) - 2*p**3*ya*sin(beta) + 2*p**3*yd*sin(beta) - 3*p**2*xa*cos(beta) + 3*p**2*xd*cos(beta) + 3*p**2*ya*sin(beta) - 3*p**2*yd*sin(beta) + xa*cos(beta) - xm*cos(beta) - ya*sin(beta) + ym*sin(beta))/(3*p*(p - 1)**2*sin(alpha - beta))

abq = -(2*q**3*xa*cos(beta) - 2*q**3*xd*cos(beta) - 2*q**3*ya*sin(beta) + 2*q**3*yd*sin(beta) - 3*q**2*xa*cos(beta) + 3*q**2*xd*cos(beta) + 3*q**2*ya*sin(beta) - 3*q**2*yd*sin(beta) + xa*cos(beta) - xn*cos(beta) - ya*sin(beta) + yn*sin(beta))/(3*q*(q - 1)**2*sin(alpha - beta))
```

when I try to solve for q when abp = abq, python process hangs.
Could anyone inform me the kinds of equations sympy has difficulty solving ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is unwieldy (it would probably be better to substitute in values for all but q and then use `nsolve` to solve the equation) but if you use `simplify=False, check=False` the solution will be obtained fairly quickly.

```
>>> gsol = solve(eqpq, q, check=False, simplify=False)
>>> reps = {xd: 10, beta: 11, ya: 12, alpha: 13,
...         p: 14, xn: 15, yn: 16, xa: 17, yd: 18, xm: 20, ym: 21}
>>> [i.n(3, subs=reps, chop=True) for i in gsol]  # slow
[0.416, 1.61, 13.9]
>>> [i.subs(reps).n(3,chop=True) for i in gsol]  # faster
[0.416, 1.61, 13.9]
>>> neq = eqpq.rewrite(Add).as_numer_denom()[0].subs(reps).n()
>>> [i.n(3) for i in real_roots(neq)]  # very fast
[0.416, 1.61, 13.9]
```

In the slowest case, more care is taken to make sure the answer is correct. In the last case, the numerical values are substituted into the expression and just the numerator is retained and the real roots of that are requested.

Comment: I need a general equation not values

Comment: That's what `gsol` is -- the symbolic solution.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, Let me try it